# Querying Many To Many relationship in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I'm experimenting with Django and I'm trying to figure out Many to Many Relationships. Let's say I have certain model named "Facility", similarly I created another model named "Hotels" which contains fields 'facility' and 'featured_facility' both are in Many To Many relationship with "Facility". I want to add featured_facility only if it is available in 'facility' fields how can I do that? Here is my models code.

```
class Facility(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        validators=[validate_facility_name],
        unique=True,
    )
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[validate_facility_description])
    can_be_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

similarly Hotel model is

```
class Hotels(models.Model):
    hotel_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        unique=True,
        validators=[validate_hotel_name]
    
    facility = models.ManyToManyField(
        Facility,
        related_name='hotel_facility',
        blank=True,
    )
    featured_facility = models.ManyToManyField(
        Facility,
        related_name='featured_hotel_facility',
        blank=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        default_permissions = ()
        verbose_name = 'Hotel'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Hotels'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hotel_name
```

Now I want to add 'featured_facility' only if it is available in 'facility' no new featured facility from Facility can be added in 'featured_facility' I am stucked on querying many to many relationship part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this way

```
def _factory(self):
    featured_facility = Facility.objects.filter(can_be_featured=True)
    # print(featured_facility, '-------', self._data.get('facility'))
    if set(self._data.get('facility')).issubset(set(featured_facility)):
        self._bus.featured_facility.add(*self._data.get('facility'))
    else:
        raise ValidationError({'error': _('This facility is not featured at the moment.')})
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this

```
f = Facility(name='hello', can_be_featured=True, ...)
f1 = Facility(name='hello2', can_be_featured=True, ...)

hotel = Hotels.objects.first()
hotel.facility.add(f)

if f1 in hotel.facility.all():
   hotel.featured_facility.add(f1)
```

Comment: is this applicable in model methods under def_clean()?